# Add dynamic div with ascending loop on click

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, addition, counter

I want to creat a function on click that adds a new div to a dom element. Every time i click on the add button an new div shoud be added:
first click:

```
<div id="draggeble0"></div>
```

second click

```
<div id="draggeble2"></div>
```

third click

```
<div id="draggeble2"></div>
```

and sow on

my code now:

```
$(".add-btn").click(function() {
$(".stage").append('<div id="draggable1"></div>');
});
```

Comment: check you have same id `<div id="draggeble2"></div>` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$(".add-btn").click(function () {
    $(".stage").append('<div id="draggable'+(i++)+'"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Can each be used instead?

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to use it but you technically can.